# What's the best method of creating a SSRS report that will be run manually many times with different Parameters?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a SSRS Sales report that will be run many times a day by users, but with different parameters selected for the branch and product types.

The SQL query uses some large tables and is quite complex, therefore, running it many times is going to have a performance cost.

I assumed the best solution would be to create a dataset for the report with all permutations, ran once overnight and then apply filters when the users run the report.

I tried creating a snapshot in SSRS which doesn’t consider the parameters and therefore has all the required data, then filtering the Tablix using the parameters that the users selected. The snapshot works fine but it appears to be refreshed when the report is run with different parameters.

My next solution would be to create a table for the dataset which the report would then point to. I could recreate the table every night using a stored procedure. With a couple of small indexes the report would be lightning fast.

This solution would seem to work really well but my knowledge of SQL is limited, and I can’t help thinking this is not the right solution.

Is this suitable? Are there better ways? Can anybody confirm either way?

Comment: Like anything it depends on your individual requirements, but when I have been faced with reports like this I build a 'reportcache' table that contains just the data required. I normally add this to the process that updates the data in the base tables but that's just how our data gets updated (in batches). If overnight is a safe time then why not, as you suggest, refresh the 'reportcache' table then. I usually also have a report that calls the refresh too, that way users can update the data on demand if absolutely required. Include a "lastupdated" timestamp that you can show on the report too.

Comment: Thanks Alan, your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS datasets have caching capabilities. I think you'll find this more useful instead of having to create extra db tables and such.

Please see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/cache-shared-datasets-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

If the rate of change of the data is low enough, and [SSRS Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/cache-shared-datasets-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't suit your needs, then you could manually cache the record set from the report query (without the filtering) into its own table, then you can modify the report to query from that table.

> Oracle and most Data Warehouse implementations have a formal mechanism specifically for this called [Materialized Views](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-views#C6), no such luck in SQL server though you can easily implement the same pattern yourself.

There are 2 significant drawbacks to this:

1. The data in the new table is a snapshot at the point in time that it was loaded, so this technique is better suited to slow moving datasets or reports where it is not critical that the data is 100% accurate.
2. You will need to manage the lifecycle of the data in this table, ideally you should setup a Job or Scheduled Task to automate this refresh but you could trigger a refresh as part of the logic in your report *(not recommended, but possible)*.

   - Though it is possible, you would *NOT* consider using a TRIGGER to update the data as you have already indicated the query takes some time to execute, this could have a major impact on the rest of your LOB application

If you do go down this path you should write the refresh logic into a stored procedure so that it can be executed when needed and from other internal and external automation mechanisms.

You should also add a column that records the date and time of when the dataset was executed, then replace any references in your report that display the date and time the report was printed, with the time the data was prepared.

---

It is also worth pointing out that often performance issues with expensive queries in SSRS reports can be overcome if you can reducing the functions and value formatting that is in the SQL query itself and move that logic into the report definition. This goes for filtering operations too, you can easily add additional computed columns in the dataset definition or in the design surface and you can implement filtering directly in the tablix too, there is no requirement that every record from the SQL query be displayed in the report at all, just as we do not need to show every column.

Sometimes some well crafted indexes can help too, for complicated reports we can often find a balance between what the SQL engine can do efficiently and what the RDL can do for us.

*Disclaimer: This is hypothetical advice, you should evaluate each report on a case by case basis.*